# двумерный массив и соседние элементы в нем

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

есть у нас массив(размер не важен), задача стоит такая: Определить, сколько в нем пар соседних одинаковых элементов. Элементы считаются соседними, если их индексы в столбцах и/или в строках различаются не более чем на единицу. Задача показалась изначально не сложной, но после нескольких часов думок убедился в обратном. Внимание, код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
    const int n = 4;
    const int m =4;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    printf("Заполните массив:\n ");
    int a[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            //printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            //scanf_s("%d", &a[i][j]);
            a[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    int k=0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        
        for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == a[i + 1][j]) {
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 1; j < m-1; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == a[i][j+1]) {
                k++;
            }
        }
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("k=%d", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Честно говоря, шестеренки в голове уже заели, и сам найти ошибку не в силах

пример:[image: су]

сам сейчас задумался, а сколько же тут пар одинаковых чисел, подсчитал, что 10, но выводит 6, что будет правильным ответом, если считать пары только горизонтально. Думаю, что в этом как раз и ошибка, но как точно проверить нижнее или верхнее число n-го элемента матрицы?

Comment: В вашем вопросе отсутвует вопрос.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++)` а чего циклы то с 1 начинаете, в сях они с 0 же вроде

Comment: вопрос "как и где исправить ошибку в коде и получить корректный ответ" - не слишком банальный?

Comment: так что такое "корректный ответ"? Где примеры данных на входе и выходе? Говорите про ошибку в коде, но что это за ошибка? Мало инфы даете же

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с информацией из справки [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @tym32167 дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чутка переписал алгоритм - просто пробегаю по матрице и проверяю пару справа и снизу (когда есть ячейка справа и снизу)

```
var data = new[] { 
    new[] {1, 1, 1, 1}, 
    new[] {1, 1, 1, 1}, 
    new[] {2, 3, 4, 5}, 
    new[] {6, 7, 8, 9}};

int n=4, m=4;
int k=0;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
{
    if (i < n-1 && data[i][j] == data[i+1][j]) k++;
    if (j < m-1 && data[i][j] == data[i][j+1]) k++;
}

Console.WriteLine(k);
```

Вывод

```
10
```

Comment: отлично, но что не так было в моем коде? алгоритм вроде бы у нас схож, но ответы разные..                                и еще, не отходя от темы массивов, как заполнить да и вообще объявить двумерный массив NxM размера, который дальше заполняет сам пользователь? Компилятор ругается, что если записать массив как `a[N][M]`, но перед этим эти значения вводит пользователь, то их нельзя использовать, как константы

Comment: понимаю, что константы - это то, что не изменяется в ходе всей программы, но как тогда объявлять такой двумерный массив?

Comment: 1) что у вас не так: вы циклы почему то с 1 начинаете, а не с 0, а значит вы игнорируете первые столбец и строку

Comment: 2) Как объявлять массивы в сях - не имею понятия, я пишу на дотнете

Comment: а какую проверку добавить, чтобы проверялись еще и диагонали? i+1 и j+1 + добавить проверку, чтобы не выходить за границы - до этого я додумался, но что делать для другой диагонали? i-1 и j-1? тогда что делать с первыми элементами первого столбца?

Comment: @ualdrm `i+1 и j+1` и `i-1 и j-1` - это одна и та же диагональ, но вообще задавайте новый вопрос, если у вас новые условия

Answer (score -1):

Не путай c/c++ с паскалем, здесь массив может быть только линейным.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/807326)

Comment: Ну вот представьте себе: Я спрошу: «Как мне слетать на Луну на метле?». Вы ответите: «Никак». А кто-то придёт со своим «умным» замечанием: «Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению».

Comment: Я скорее отвечу -- следует построить ракету и назвать её "метла" :)  Замечания по поводу вопроса следует указывать в комментариях, тем более что кармы у вас достаточно.  И весьма похоже, что автор вопроса умышленно применял индексы от 1 и до n - 1 / m - 1, чтобы не выйти за пределы строки/столбца и избежать лишних проверок для краевых элементов.

Comment: Вот как раз это ответом не будет. И очевидно же, что в линейном массиве не может быть ни строк, ни столбцов.

Comment: В каком _линейном_ массиве? [Массивы в C (часть 2): многомерные массивы](http://cppstudio.com/post/9407/), [Керниган, Ричи: 5.7. Многомерные массивы](http://www.rabus.ru/KernighanRitchie_C/ch5kr.html#p57)

Comment: И множество квадратных скобок подряд Вас не смущает?

Comment: int checkers[8][8]; – не двумерный массив, а массив массивов. А двумерный – это checkers:array[0..7, 0..7] of real;, позволяющий указать оба индекса в одних скобках.

Comment: Получается массив может быть двумерным только в том случае, если оба индекса можно указать в одних скобках?

Comment: Массив может быть двумерными только в том случае, если он двумерен. Разумеется, он адресуется двумя индексами в одном операторе. А как же ещё? На паскале многомерный массив – синоним массива массивов, но паскаль – не c. Если cherkers[i], то уже получаем элемент с одним индексом, а следующие [j] – это уже адресация его элемента, а не элемента всего cherkers.

Comment: На любом поддерживающим массивы массивов языке можно представить многомерный массив массивом массивов и на любом поддерживающим многомерные массивы языке можно представить массив массивов одинаковых размеров многомерным массивом. Но это только ВАША ИНТЕРПРЕТАЦИЯ, в тексте же будет только то, что там написано. А написано может быть только то, что поддерживается языком.

Comment: Вот представьте себе, что вместо физического массива у вас четырёхсвязный список, одна пара указателей в каждом элементе указывает влево и вправо (по одному указателю в каждую сторону), другая – вверх и вниз. Если язык поддерживает и перегрузку операторов, и многомерные массивы, то при поиске элемента можно чередовать использование указателей вправо и указателей вниз. А если нет, то нет.

Comment: Или физический массив – линерализованный массив. Если язык поддерживает и перегрузку операторов, и многомерные массивы, то можно вычислить внутренний индекс по всем внешним сразу. А если нет, то нельзя линерализовать физический массив вообще, а придётся сначала вычислить адрес массива, являющегося элементом, а только потом в его операторе квадратные скобки – адрес его элемента. Ну или выкручиваться функциями вместо операторов.